# rsync with link-dest and empty directories

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

When using rsync with --link-dest, rsync does not copy empty directories from source to destination, a file has to change for that to happen.

Is there anyway to force it to create the empty directories?

Answer (score 1):

You could run an additional rsync to create the empty directories:

> rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" `<src>` `<dest>`